# I always get "success":false as response from google recaptcha version 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, recaptcha

I always get "success":false as response from google(no error messages), but the captcha from google shows me that the input was right.

[This](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) is where I got my informatins from.

THis is what I tried, I also sent this with "PostMan"(chrome addon), and JQuery.Post.. :

```
 var userInput=req.body["g-recaptcha-response"]? "&response="+req.body["g-recaptcha-response"]:"";
        var remoteIp="&remoteip="+req.connection.remoteAddress;

        var finalRequest="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=..."+userInput;//+remoteIp;

        request({
            uri: finalRequest,
            method: "POST",
            timeout: 10000,
            followRedirect: true,
            maxRedirects: 10
        }, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log(body);

        });
```

Comment: What does `console.log(body)` actually display? Does it contain error code(s)? Also, have you verified that `console.dir(req.body["g-recaptcha-response"])` displays the expected value?

Comment: Yes, i verified that using webstrom(set break points and steped through). Console responses: {
  "success": false
}.(no errors are sent from google).req.body["g-recaptcha-response"] has a value. That is the strange thing...

Comment: Did you try posting an actual form instead of passing them through the url? For example: `request({ url: "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", form: { secret: secret, response: req.body["g-recaptcha-response"] }, ...}, function(error, response, body) {...})`

Comment: pretty sure you should encodeURIComponent some of that stuff.. but probably not why its failing.  var userInput=req.body["g-recaptcha-response"]? "&response="+encodeURIComponent(req.body["g-recaptcha-response"]):"";
~~